# Iframe Passing variables and capture then in landing page

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am using an Iframe. I need to pass some variables (a and b) and capture them in the landing page.

**Page -1**

```
  <iframe id="trackFrame" width="600" height="500"  src="maps.html?A=1&B=2" frameborder="0"      
   scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe>
```

In the landing page I need to

**Landing Page**

```
  <body onload="initialize(passedA, passedB)">
```

Please help me I m new to presentation development.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at this post here: [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

First you will need to get an array of the parameters passed, which can be done via:

```
var newArray = window.location.search.substr(1).split('&')
```

try calling a blank function on pageLoad that then reads this. 
The array is then created by reading the param string `window.location.search.substr(1)`
and then splits everything into an array seperated by the & field.

So if you had mysite.com/page.html?a=3&b=4 it would create an array with

```
newArray(0) = "a=3" and newArray(1) = "b=4"
```

then

```
var a = newArray(0).substring(2)
var b = newArray(1).substring(2)
```

the substring(2) will removed the "a=" and "b=" from the parameter and leave you with your end results for the parameters passed.

This should help you start.